# ASP:RadioButtonList non unique values?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I've got a strange questions and more than likely a simple answer so here goes.
I have created a few web forms that hook up with a table and save the values of the selected radiobuttonlists. In a few cases there may be a few listitems that have the same value but different text such as

```
<asp:RadionButtonList runat="server" id="RadioButtonList1">
   <asp:ListItem Value="2">Yes</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="2">Of course</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="0">No</asp:ListItem>
</RadioButtonList>
```

For the rest of the radiobuttonlist's where values are all unique I just fill them out with

```
me.RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue = dr("ValueA")
```

I have tried to save the selectedindex and fill it that way with

```
me.RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = dr("ValueAIndex")
```

But this just will go to the top listitem of that value rather than the correct one.

Any help would be awesome!
Many thanks!
Dan

Comment: Is there anyway you can generate a unique value for the list?  Add some additional piece of data to the value?

Comment: If you mean reselecting the correct radio button then you will have to store something that is unique between all the possible items.

Comment: Reading what you have said above is the simple answer that values must be unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the only unique item is the `Text` to search on, could you do:

```
 RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 
     RadioButtonList1.Items.IndexOf(
         RadioButtonList1.Items.FindByText("ValueAText"));
```

Make sure to put in checks for `FindByText` failing.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out when I get into work in the morning :)